# regular expressions - best practice with regards to match or matches methods

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am doing some regex queries in an VB.net environment.

Basically I have to say that my knowledge around regex is a little above beginners level.

Most of my queries look like this:

```
Dim regProj As Regex = New Regex("(?<=\x01)[A-Z]{2}\x02.+?(?=\x03)")
Dim Mtch = regProj.Match(ProjektCodes)

While Mtch.Success

   If Mtch.Value.ToUpper.Substring(3) = sTempArr(1).ToUpper Then

       ProjektCode = Mtch.Value
       Exit While

    End If

    Mtch = Mtch.NextMatch

End While
```

My question now is - Is there a difference with positive/negative effect to the query performance if I do it as shown in the example or if I would use

```
Dim MtchColl = regProj.Matches(ProjektCodes)
```

and iterate the Collection afterwards?

Any idea is very welcome!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Couldn't you test the performance yourself? What do those tests reveal? What then is your question?

Comment: There are a lot of good resources available out there, I'd suggest doing some research first and then returning to this site if you have a specific problem that you encounter. This article should be a good start to avoid anything completely devastating https://wanago.io/2019/09/23/regex-course-part-four-avoiding-catastrophic-backtracking-using-lookahead/